# Why does Ruby convert `string.chr` values to `?`?

Tags: ruby

I want to shift the chr value of the characters in a string by a certain amount. This code:

```
def encrypt2(word, num)
  cipher = word.split('').map{|e|
    e = e.ord + num
    e = e.chr
  }.join.reverse
  puts cipher
end

encrypt2('hellozz', 10)
```

outputs: `??yvvor`. It seems that after `126.chr`, it only returns question marks.

Comment: Because your console isn't showing non-ASCII (< 128) characters? If the point is to have an ASCII-based transposition cipher you can't blindly add, you need to rotate/modulo/etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton the problem is exactly an opposite. The resulting symbol is not well-formed UTF-8 symbol, since those starting with `(128..256)` are supposed to have _two bytes_.

Answer (score 0):

`e = e.ord + num` will produce non-ASCII characters.

You can make use the `String#next` method to get the next ASCII character for a given character.  However, `'z'.next` will be `'aa'` due to the carry created, hence, in such cases one has to pick the first character of that result.

So, you could write:

```
num.times { e = e.next[0]}
```

---

```
def encrypt2(word, num)
    word.chars.map {|e| num.times {e = e.next[0]}; e}.join.reverse
end

puts encrypt2('hellozz', 10)
#=> "jjyvvor"

puts encrypt2("naïve", 1)
#=> fwðbo
```

Comment: Assigning `cipher` var is redundant.

Comment: @mudasobwa  Good point - I just copied the OP's code, will fix it.

Comment: There's really no reason for this to be a one-liner. Easy-to-read code is always better than terse code.